# Adding an icon to right-to-left ListView items causes the icons to flip in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `ListView`. Its `RightToLeft` property is set to `Yes` and its `RightToLeftLayout` is set to `True`. The `ListView` is populated with files in a directory.

In my code, I get the appropriate icon of a file using `System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(string filePath)` and assign it to the file. This means that the icon come directly from the operating system. I do not have a directory with custom icons.

So the result is this:
[image: Demonstration]

As you can see, the PowerPoint file icon is flipped. When I change the layout to `LeftToRight` it is shown perfectly. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you set it to LeftToRight on the icon itself?

Comment: @Will The icons are loaded from the OP itself. I do not have a directory containing several icons. I will update the question with this information.

Comment: Yes, but the control in your UI, can you specify that the icon control in your form is LTR?  I don't know offhand, forms eew.

Comment: I do not quite understand what do you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The icon in the form.  It has to be inside some kind of icon control.  That's a control.  Like all other forms controls.  It might have that RTL property on it.  I can't tell, because instead of code you have an image.  You get a System.Drawing.Icon from the OS, but how do you cram that into your UI?

Comment: Ho. Now I understand. It's an `ImageList`. And it doesn't have a RTL property.

Comment: That's too bad.  There's got to be a way to visually flip the image, either by flipping the control (in WPF you could use a render transform that flips the image) or by simply flipping the image in code after you get it.  Not sure how to do that, but it'll give you something to search for.  For example, check the code here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rotatefliptype(v=vs.110).aspx Good luck.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip(v=vs.110).aspx
Maybe this helps you with flipping the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the icon to be reversed, I suggest putting it into a `Bitmap` then using the `Bitmap.RotateFlip` you can flip it horizontally.

```
Bitmap bm = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(string filePath).ToBitmap();
bm.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
```